# Execute different functions in Function File

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, outlook-web-addins

```
    I am trying to develop an outlook plugin which can open different kind of links based on user button clicked.
```

This is my manifest file code :

```
    <Hosts>
          <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
              <FunctionFile resid="Commands.js"/>
              <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                  <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                    <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="DefectButtonMenu">
                      <Label resid="DefectButton.Label"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="DefectButton.Label"/>
                        <Description resid="DefectButton.Tooltip"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Icon>
                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="DefectImg"/>
                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="DefectImg"/>
                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="DefectImg"/>
                      </Icon>
                      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>defect</FunctionName>
                      </Action>
                    </Control>
                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskButtonMenu">
                      <Label resid="TaskButton.Label"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="TaskButton.Label"/>
                        <Description resid="TaskButton.Tooltip"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Icon>
                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="TaskImg"/>
                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="TaskImg"/>
                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="TaskImg"/>
                      </Icon>
                      <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>task</FunctionName>
                      </Action>
                    </Control>       
                  </Group>
                </OfficeTab>
              </ExtensionPoint>
            </DesktopFormFactor>
          </Host>
        </Hosts>
```

Commands.js file:

```
    Office.onReady(() => {
      // If needed, Office.js is ready to be called
    });
    
    /**
     * Shows a notification when the add-in command is executed.
     * @param event {Office.AddinCommands.Event}
     */
    function action(event) {
      const message = {
        type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
        message: "Performed action.",
        icon: "Icon.80x80",
        persistent: true,
      };
    
      // Show a notification message
      Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);
      // Be sure to indicate when the add-in command function is complete
      event.completed();
    }
    
    function defect(event) {
      const message = {
        type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
        message: "WorkItem Creation done...!",
        icon: "Icon.80x80",
        persistent: true,
      };
    
      // Show a notification message
      Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);
      //var defectItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    
      window.open("https://somerandomwebsite.com/defectpage");
    
      // Be sure to indicate when the add-in command function is complete
      event.completed();
    }
    
    function task(event) {
      const message = {
        type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
        message: "Item Creation done...!",
        icon: "Icon.80x80",
        persistent: true,
      };
    
      // Show a notification message
      Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);
      //var defectItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    
      window.open("https://somerandomwebsite.com/taskpage");
    
      // Be sure to indicate when the add-in command function is complete
      event.completed();
    }
    
    function getGlobal() {
      return typeof self !== "undefined"
        ? self
        : typeof window !== "undefined"
        ? window
        : typeof global !== "undefined"
        ? global
        : undefined;
    }
    
    const g = getGlobal();
    
    // The add-in command functions need to be available in global scope
    g.action = action;
```

However whenever i click on "Defect" button or "Task" button, the respective functions are not called. But if i place the link ("https://somerandomwebsite.com/taskpage") in action(event) function and call action in

```
 <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                      </Action>
```

it executes. Please help me on how i can correctly call the functions.

Answer (score 0):

In the commands.html file, make sure to include these script lines:

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Commands.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If ur javascript functions code is present in "Commands.js"